# How to pass the id of an element that triggers an `onclick` event to the event handling function

Tags: javascript, html

How do I pass the id of an element that triggers an `onclick` event to the event handling function.

I am doing something like this-

```
<link onclick="doWithThisElement(id_of_this_element)" />
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Instead of passing the ID, you can just pass the element itself:

```
<link onclick="doWithThisElement(this)" />
```

Or, if you insist on passing the ID:

```
<link id="foo" onclick="doWithThisElement(this.id)" />
```

Here's the JSFiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/dRkuv/

Comment: Agreed, you probably don't need an id at all.

Comment: I really appreciate your demo weblink! Thanks for the effort!

Comment: No problem.  While this is a quick, simple answer, take note of the topics Felix discusses.  Event handling can get complicated with bubbling.

Comment: Does this works on a keyboard event ?

Comment: There is typo in JSFiddle, labels for "Pass Element" and "Pass Id" are misplaced.

Answer (score 18):

The element that triggered the event can be different than the one you bound the handler to because events [*bubble up the DOM tree*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

So if you want to get the ID of the element *the event handler is bound to*, you can do this easily with `this.id` (`this` refers to the element).

But if you want to get the element where the event *originated*, then you have to access it with `event.target` in W3C compatible browsers and `event.srcElement` in IE 8 and below.

I would avoid writing a lot of JavaScript in the `onXXXX` HTML attributes. I would only pass the `event` object and put the code to extract the element in the handler (or in an extra  function):

```
<div onlick="doWithThisElement(event)">
```

Then the handler would look like this:

```
function doWithThisElement(event) {
    event = event || window.event; // IE
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE

    var id = target.id;
    //...
}
```

I suggest to read the [excellent articles about event handling at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

---

Btw

```
<link onclick="doWithThisElement(id_of_this_element)" />
```

does hardly make sense (`<link>` is an element that can only appear in the `<head>`, binding an event handler (if even possible) will have no effect).

Comment: Felix, could you check my edit (`var taget` to `var target`)? I assumed it was a typo; but I'd prefer you to check just so's I didn't screw up your example... =/

Comment: Really nice explanation!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) but [cross-browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller#Browser_compatibility) method that may be useful if you don't want to pass any arguments:-

Html:

```
<div onclick=myHandler() id="my element's id">&rarr; Click Here! &larr;</div>
```

Script:

```
function myHandler(){
    alert(myHandler.caller.arguments[0].target.id)
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/mrmoje/pen/ouJtk

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the use of jquery mate.

With jQuery you would then be able to get the id of this element by

> $(this).attr('id');

without jquery, if I remember correctly we used to access the id with a

> this.id

Hope that helps :)

Comment: +1, but 'we used to access the id...'? ...I still do. It's (usually) faster and easier than most of the library alternatives.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, and I don't know why you are recommending jQuery for a pretty simple task.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<link onclick='doWithThisElement(this.attributes["id"].value)' />
```

In the context of the onclick JavaScript, **this** refers to the current element (which in this case is the whole HTML element **link**).

Comment: Never saw that before, just  tried it out and doesn't work.. also, you are missing a right bracket m8...

Comment: @SaeedNeamati: Then change it. Your code is not correct and has syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" >
function openOnImageClick(event)
{
//alert("Jai Sh Raam");
// document.getElementById("images").src = "fruits.jpg";
var target = event.target || event.srcElement; // IE

console.log(target);
console.log(target.id);
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 img.setAttribute('src', target.src);
  img.setAttribute('width', '200');
   img.setAttribute('height', '150');
  document.getElementById("images").appendChild(img);


}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Screen Shot View</h1>
<p>Click the Tiger to display the Image</p>

<div id="images" >
</div>

<img id="muID1" src="tiger.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick(event)" />
<img id="myID2" src="sabaLogo1.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick(event)" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We can <img id="myID" src="tiger.jpg" width="100" height="50" alt="unfinished bingo card" onclick="openOnImageClick(event)" />, now when click on this image will pass the whole target ang get it there

Comment: Edit your answer with contents you posted above. Don't post answers on comments.

Answer (score 0):

> if click any button, it will be call the function and add classList
> active class

```
<label for="natural" id="natural" class="Natural" onclick="showContent(this)">Natural</label>

            <label for="labgrown" id="labgrown" class="Labgrown" onclick="showContent(this)">Labgrown </label>

            <label for="fancyColor" id="fancy" class="Fancy" onclick="showContent(this)">Fancy</label>

<script>
    function showContent(event) {
        $(event).addClass("active");
        console.log(jenil);
    }
    
</script>
```