# Onclick event act on specific button

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, onclick

I have a function called changeImage and I would like to change only the button I have clicked. 
How can I achieve that? I don't think that hard code is the solution. I am using PHP and javascript.
*I have about 100 buttons and each one has its own ID eg: A1,A2,B1,B2

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImage() {
            var image = document.getElementById('A1');
            if (image.src.match("Grey")) {
                image.src = "Image/Yellow.png";
            } else {
                image.src = "Image/Grey.png";
                return false;
        }
    }</script>
<input id="A1" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage()">
<input id="A2" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage()">
<input id="B1" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage()">
<input id="B2" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of calling a certain id use `this` command. Like if this button is clicked change its source

```
   function changeImage(button) {   //button = this onclick="changeImage(button)";
        if (button.src.match("Grey")) {
            button.src = "Image/Yellow.png";
        } else {
            button.src = "Image/Grey.png";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Check in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7pqaqLk/)

Answer (score 2):

Use this code instead :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeImage(e) {
        var image = e;
        if (image.src.match("Grey")) {
            image.src = "Image/Yellow.png";
        } else {
            image.src = "Image/Grey.png";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<input id="A1" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
<input id="A2" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
<input id="B1" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
<input id="B2" type="image" src="Image/Grey.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a variable through the function parameters, and pick it up inside the function, as exhibited here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575272/1864597.

If you don't need to pass any variables (and want to keep it cleaner), use the answer by @developer.